# Пересчет цен с учетом наценки

Tags: php

Мне необходимо сделать наценку на товар на определенный процент.

Вроде несложно:

```
function _getPercentPrice($price, $percent)
{
    $result = $price / 100 * $percent;
    $result = $result + $percent;
    return round($result);
}
```

Однако выходит так:

- 179 - реальная цена товара
- 190 - цена товара + процент (наценка в 4%)
- 749 - цена товара * количество (4 в корзине) + процент.

Видно, что идет округление, и из-за этого суммы разные.

Что тут можно сделать? Всё время суммы разные.

Comment: 179 и 4 % наценки разве не 186,16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам не нужно округление? Тогда просто уберите его и округляйте уже после всех математических операций. И зачем вы складываете теплое с мягким в итоге (`$result + $percent`)?

Вот так попробуйте:

```
function _getPercentPrice($price, $percent)
{
    return $price / 100 * $percent + $price;
}
```

Comment: У вас выходит также. Цена товара с 4 процентами 186, все верно, а вот с количеством 4 уже 745, а должно быть 744. Что и где округлять я вот понять и не могу, что четко все было.

Comment: @drop_off, так сначала считайте товар с наценкой для одного экземпляра и только потом умножайте на количество товара.

Comment: @Visman так и делаю. Беру полученную сумму с процентом и умножаю на количество.

Comment: @drop_off, не верю. Смотрю на ваш первый комментарий к этому ответу: `Цена товара с 4 процентами 186` и делаю 186 х 4 = **744**, а вы пишите `а вот с количеством 4 уже 745`. Что скажите?

Comment: Мы здесь явно выходим за рамки исходного вопроса. Метод получения процента у нас правильный, а вот на 4 умножается как-то не так.

Comment: @Andrew Godin спасибо за помощь! Я понял в чем косяк.

Comment: @Andrew Godin, это как с налоговой, которая требует, чтобы налог на ФОТ с точностью до копейки сходился с процентом от общей суммы и их не волнует, что на предприятии работает несколько сотен человек.

Answer (score 1):

```
function _getPercentPrice($price, $percent)
{
    $result = $price*$percent/100;
    $result += $price;
    return round($result);
}
```

**UPD**
В моем ответе изменена логика подсчета процента, а именно -  `price*percent/100`.

Comment: @Regent в том, что код из вопроса возвращает `11`, и если присмотреться, то коды не одинаковые.

Comment: @Regent код слишком короткий и изменения очевидны, я думаю. Но раз просите, сейчас обновлю ответ.

Comment: Сегодня я не заметил, что там `$price`, а не `$percent`, завтра - ещё кто-нибудь... Да и то, что для одного очевидно, для другого может быть не очевидно. Строка-другая текста помогает понять идею всем.

Comment: @Regent ок, только не удаляйте свои комментария.

Comment: _"изменена логика подсчета процента"_ - так ведь `price * percent / 100` работает так же, как и `price / 100 * percent`? Неужто в PHP по умолчанию целочисленное деление? По-моему, главное отличие во второе строке: `$result += $price;`.

Comment: Комментарии, которые более не актуальны, я удаляю. Зачем им оставаться? Вы можете поступить со своими так же.

Comment: @Regent `$result = $result + $price` и `$result += $price` - одно и то же

Comment: Безоговорочно. Только вот в вопросе `$result = $result + $percent;`.

Comment: @Regent а вот в комментарии к ответу - прояснение.

Comment: А я вам не предлагаю все свои комментарии удалять. Но, например, "Regent код слишком короткий и изменения очевидны, я думаю. Но раз просите, сейчас обновлю ответ." уже точно не актуален: ответ вы уже обновили.

Answer (score 1):

*Немного теории из предметной области.* Есть математическое округление, а есть округление [банковское (бухгалтерское)](http://stan-1.ru/bankovskoe-okruglenie-okazyvaetsya-est-i-takoe/). Еще одно название — [гауссово округление](http://geodesist.ru/forum/threads/okruglenie-v-geodezii.6623/). Программисты почему-то про него постоянно забывают.

При вычислении процентов в работе с ценами появляются суммы с десяти- и стотысячными долями значений, которые при последующем суммировании и округлении приводят к накоплению **ошибки округления**. Полностью эту ошибку снять нельзя, но можно сократить вероятность ее накопления.

Банковское округление работает таким образом. **Все числа, у которых тысячная доля рубля не равна 5, округляются по правилам математического округления**. А другие по следующему правилу:

- если цифра, которая стоит перед цифрой 5, четная, — **округляем в меньшую сторону**,
- если цифра, которая стоит перед цифрой 5, нечетная, — **округляем в большую сторону**.

Функция PHP, возвращающая корректно округленную стоимость ([взято из комментариев к указанной выше статье](http://stan-1.ru/bankovskoe-okruglenie-okazyvaetsya-est-i-takoe/)):

```
function bround($val) {

    $x = intval(abs($val) * 1000);

    if ($val && (($x % 10) == 5)){

        $tmp = intval(abs($val) * 100);

        if ($tmp % 2 != 0)
            $tmp += 1;

        if ($val < 0)
            $tmp = 0 — $tmp;

        $amount = $tmp / 100;

    }else{

        $amount = round($val, 2);

    }

    return (float)$amount;
}
```

Бонус. [Функция банковского округления для JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3108986/1036370).